# How to access a div tag content using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm currently working on creating a test which will be able to click a link which is in a div. The problem is my developer has changed some part of the UI and as a result my XPath locator is not working. Also using Xpath is not feasible as in future some UI might change and I wont be able to locate the element.

My div tag looks like this and I want to perform a click on the div tag.

```
<div class="link verticalCenter" ng-click="replaceLocation('login')">Sign in</div>
```

PS: I can't use css locator for it.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: Where is the `div `tag?

Comment: Not enough information to help. Provide a reasonable sample snippet of html, your current locator strategy in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [relative `XPath`](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/xpath.html) that will be still applicable after changes in `DOM`:

```
//div[text()="Sign in"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You still might use CSS, but with some special locator:
`element(by.cssContainingText('div', 'Sign in'))`

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText